# How to download and install fqrx-amcccle to Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: ati, graphics, fglrx

Background:

In Ubuntu Software Center there is ''fqrx-amdcccle'', version 2-15.200-Oubuntu4.

I installed this to my Ubuntu 15.04. After installation my laptop did not acknowledge any more my password. Result: I had to re-install OS.

( My laptop is HP  EliteBook 8530p with Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T9550 @ 2.66GHz × 2, 64bit, RAM 4G and with graphics Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV635. Earlier I installed this AMD CCC and it worked fine on this same laptop, this laptop  was then with OS Windows Vista Prof )

Questions:

1. Doeas fqrx-amdcccle work OK in 15.04 ?
2. I saw in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evqpassbyqA  short film describing in detail how to install fqlrx-amdcccle to Ubuntu 14.04. Is  this same instruction / procedure valid still also for Ubuntu 15.04 or how it is changed ? If changed, how ?
3. Should I install also ''fqlrx-amdcccle-updates'' or something else to make it working OK ?
4. Should I do some other addtional settings after installation ?

Brgds,
Kauko Peltonen

Comment: Sorry,  my missprint: fqlrx-amdcccle, version is 2:15.200-Oubuntu4. Kauko Peltonen

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your post to fix your mistake and, by the way, it's `fglrx-amdcccle`. Now that that's done, yes, it will work fine. `fglrx-amdcccle` and `fglrx-amdcccle-updates` are the same package, but the `updates` one will have more frequent updates. Also, `fglrx-amdcccle` is only the Catalyst Control Center, not the actual AMD driver. If you want that, you need to install `fglrx` or `fglrx-updates`.

Comment: Zacharee1 hi,

Thanks for your kind reply ! If I understand correctly your reply, there are several possibilities of loading these different fqlrx's. I do not know which of them I need. My target / my need is the following: I want to connect my laptop with HMDI cable to TV in order to see / look my laptop screen (picture) and hear laptop (voice) from TV. What type or what kind of fqlrx I need for this purpose to this laptop? Is it only fqlrx or fqlrx with something else ? Brgds Kauko Peltonen

Comment: Either will work fine. Just get one of them.

Comment: Hi, so is only fqlrx enough for this  purpose ? Kauko Peltonen

Comment: Yes. Try them both and see what works best. Again, though it's `fGlrx`, not `fQlrx`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! OK, I'll try and let you know my result. Brgds, Kauko Peltonen

Comment: Hi, I promissed to inform the results of my fglrx installation to my 15.10. I made this installation with Synaptic which installed automatically also fglrx-amdcccle and -core. Results:  Installation was OK, but after installation 1. My Ubuntu 15.04 laptop refused to acknowledge my password anymore (=same as earlier); 2. The same after trying to restart from ''re-boot disk'' (memory stick); 3. The only way out was to reinstall OS once again from very beginning (now 3rd time because of this same reason)! Brgds, Kauko Peltonen

Comment: Bring that up as a separate question.